# how to get similar objects based on tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables like these:

- movie: id, name
- tag: id, name, value
- tagged: id, movie(FK), tag(FK)

Thus, each movie has it's own set of tags. What I need is to retrieve similar movies based on tag set. I want to get say 10 movies sorted by count of matched tags.

If I create view like below, it makes MySQL go away. There are 30k+ records in both 'tag' and 'tagged' tables.

```
create view relatedtags as 

select
    entityLeft.id as id,
    entityRight.id as rightId,
    count(rightTagged.id) as matches

from
    entity as entityLeft join tagged as leftTagged on leftTagged.entity = entityLeft.id, 
    entity as entityRight join tagged as rightTagged on rightTagged.entity = entityRight.id

where leftTagged.tag = rightTagged.tag
and entityLeft.id != entityRight.id
group by entityLeft.id, entityRight.id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will return a list of all movies that share at least 1 tag with the given `<current_movie_id>` ordered by decreasing number of tags in common

```
SELECT movie.*, count(DISTINCT similar.tag) as shared_tags FROM movie INNER JOIN 
    ( tagged AS this_movie INNER JOIN tagged AS similar USING (tag) )
    ON similar.movie = movie.id
WHERE this_movie.movie=<current_movie_id>
AND   movie.id != this_movie.movie
GROUP BY movie.id
ORDER BY shared_tags DESC
```

hope that gives you something to work with

Comment: i changed the question i bit. sorry.

Comment: ON similar.movie = tagged.movie is supposed to be ON similar.movie = this_movie.movie?

Comment: anyways the query returns nothing :(

Comment: corrected... you sure the movie has other movies with the same tags? (incidently, how do you have 30k+ distinct tags!)

Comment: actors, directors, genres, awards are all tags. there are even more than 30k :)

Comment: and yes, i am sure there are same tags for two different movies

Comment: I made a mistake (which you nearly spotted) in the join line. I also made it not return the same movie as a result

Comment: NICE! it works )) thanks alot. i will check it with huge database and respond )

Comment: I was able to use this query exactly as it is above with just renaming the tables / columns to match my schema and I was getting the results I needed.  Thanks!