# How to get similar objects based on tags using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a table with articles. Articles can have one or more tags. I'd like to retrieve simular articles based on their tags.

My table structure is very simple. It basically just a many to many relation between Articles and Tags

```
abstract class BaseArticle extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('article');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 8, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 8,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('title', 'string', null, array(
             'type' => 'string'
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {

        $this->hasMany('Articletag', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'article_id',
             'cascade'=>array('delete')));

        $this->hasMany('Dbtag as Dbtags', array('refClass'=>'Articletag',
                'local' => 'article_id',
                'foreign'=>'tag_id'
                )
        );

    }
}


abstract class BaseDbtag extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('dbtag');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 255,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('Articletag', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'tag_id'));

    }
}

abstract class BaseArticletag extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('articletag');
        $this->hasColumn('article_id', 'integer', 8, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 8,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('tag_id', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('Article', array(
             'local' => 'article_id',
             'foreign' => 'id'));

        $this->hasOne('Dbtag', array(
             'local' => 'tag_id',
             'foreign' => 'id'));
    }
}
```

What i need is to retrieve similar articles based on tag set. I want to get say 10 articles sorted by count of matched tags.

A similar problem (with movies instead of articles) is solved in native SQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237020/how-to-get-similar-objects-based-on-tags).

What is the best way to do this in Doctrine using Doctrine_Query without using native SQL?

Comment: Do you have a table structure already? Or is that what you're asking for?

Comment: I already have a table structure. I'm asking for a doctrine query.

Comment: And how are we supposed to help you with the doctrine query if we don't know what your table structure looks like? We don't have psychic powers, so first provide more info (and what you've tried already), then ask for help.

Comment: I've added the Doctrine classes and rephrased my question to make it more clear for people without psychic powers :-)